# How to download a file and zip the file?

Tags: curl, terminal, heroku-cli

How do I get a URL to download a backup from Heroku, fetch the file via curl, and zip the new file?

Heroku deliveries the url.

```
heroku pg:backups:url --app example-app | cat
```

I'm wondering if I can then curl the output of the backup into a zip file.

1. get backup file URL
2. download file from URL
3. zip of file

I'm getting lost on how to redirect the output of each command to fit this together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heroku client has a flag for downloading the dump as well

```
heroku pg:backups:download --app example-app && gzip latest.dump
```